# How to return complex objects with lazy loading to Web API

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a Web API to expose Entity framework models.

Following a number of posts I have read, I have done a few bits in my webapi.config file

```
//Ignore circular references due to the VIRTUAL property on some objects.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

//Remove XML formatter. We dont need XML, just JSON.
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

DefaultContractResolver resolver = (DefaultContractResolver)config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver;
        resolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
```

In my Web API controllers, I am disabling ProxyCreation on the DB context.

Generally this is doing what I need to. However. I need to return a UserProfile object which has a virtual UserAdditionalInfos property as below.

```
[Serializable]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<UserAdditionalInfos> AdditionalDetails { get; set; }
}
```

If I try and make an API call to get the UserProfile object, I get an error at the point it tries to lazy load the UserAdditionalInfos list.  I expect this as I have switched off the proxy creation. But if I switch it back on, I get a proxy encoded string returned in the JSON, rather than the object I would like.

Short of manually creating a 'flat' object for my API, is there any solid workaround available? Im sure this is a common problem?

Cheers

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'proxy encoded string'... if the objects are loaded and are there in the associated collection, they will be serialized as child objects in an array in the resulting JSON. Load the associated entities eagerly using Include.

Comment: By that, I mean that instead of the associated entities showing in the JSON response, I see a line say System.Dynamic_Proxies.andsomerandomnumbers.

I have heard of Include, but I am a bit puzzled where I need to do this, as I dont really want to have to start editing my db context in my business layer just to make the API work? Sorry, am a bit of a newbie at this as the Domain and Business layers were created by another dev.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to figure this out, but adding in an optional 'Includes' string in my interfaces which I then split and separate and apply to the query itself. Thanks for the insight all!